# How do I keep a constant FontSize in WPF Viewbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, font-size, viewbox

I have a `Viewbox` with a number of `TextBlock`s that are scaled and positioned perfectly by the `ViewBox`. Something like this:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Black"/>
        <TextBlock Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="12">Top Center</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

If the user resizes the `Viewbox` its contents are perfectly scaled to match. However I would like to keep the `FontSize` to 12 regardless of the actual size of the `Viewbox`.

How can I do this? Can I do this in XAML without attaching to an `Resize` event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ViewBox` won't allow you to keep a constant font size, that's just not how it works. You need to put the text outside the view box for that to happen:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
            <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="12">Top Center</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Note that I removed the Width property from the `TextBlock`, I just let it stretch for the width of the grid, letting the text alignment take care of the centering.

Or, you could get creative and bind the `FontSize` property to the `ActualWidth` of the `ViewBox` and having it scaled appropriately, for example:

Converter:

```cs
class ViewBoxConstantFontSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is double)) return null;
        double d = (double)value;
        return 100 / d * 12;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <local:ViewBoxConstantFontSizeConverter x:Key="conv"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<Viewbox Name="vb" Stretch="Uniform">
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Black"/>
        <TextBlock Width="100" TextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="{Binding ElementName=vb, 
                                      Path=ActualWidth, 
                                      Converter={StaticResource conv}}">
            Top Center
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I simplified my example a bit too much. I need the Viewbox to take care of the position of my text, but not it's FontSize.

Comment: Added an alternative to my answer, try it. It's a bit overcreative, but it might work :)

Comment: Impressive! That worked, but I was hoping for something a bit simpler.

Comment: You can also make a more general solution that is a viewbox within a viewbox with the inner viewbox dimensions bound to the outer one's with similar scaling on each dimension.

Comment: also StretchDirection="DownOnly" could be used if you just wan't it to fit if to large .

Answer (score 8):

This may be a easy fix too.

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly" >
     <Label Content="Enable" FontSize="10" FontStretch="Normal" />
</Viewbox>
```