# Fixed font size in ViewBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, font-size, viewbox

I'm programming an application in WPF(c#). I use ViewBox to make independent app to user screen size. When I resize a window (that I use ViewBox in it), font-size of all of child controls (such as button) will increase. Is there any way to avoid this problem (while size of controls can change)?

Is there any way to define a method (function) for increasing or decreasing size font?
for example for each 10pixel we change 1 level the font size?

for example:
`delta = (difference of window-size) / 10`
where delta is a value to add to font size.

Unfortunately I know that the possibility is 1% :(
I see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013854/how-do-i-keep-a-constant-fontsize-in-wpf-viewbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer:

- [How do I keep a constant FontSize in WPF Viewbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013854/how-do-i-keep-a-constant-fontsize-in-wpf-viewbox)

You can use the `ValueConverter` to calculate the rescaled font size.

Can you show us the XAML you are using inside your `ViewBox`.

Comment: The content of My ViewBox is very very huge! But it contain a child which is a Grid.