# Viewbox minimum fontsize

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a viewbox to scale a textblock.
But when the fontsize of the textblock is below a certain fontsize I want to trim the text with... and stop scalling.

How can I achieve this?

```
<Grid x:Name="UserStatusPanel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Viewbox Name="canMain" 
                MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=UserStatusPanel}"
                StretchDirection="DownOnly" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <TextBlock x:Name="UserStatusLabel" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    Text="{Binding UserStatus}" 
                    FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
                    FontSize="14" 
                    Foreground="{StaticResource AlmostWhite}"
                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is taking the text out of the viewbox and binding the font size to the viewbox width or another controller value.
[If you want an example look over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013955/2647868)

You can implement the converter with your own logics.