# Make wpf button fonts match at runtime

Tags: wpf

I have several buttons, like this:

```
  <Button Name="btnContent" Grid.Column="0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Viewbox MaxWidth="100" StretchDirection="Both">
                    <TextBlock Text="Content" ></TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Button>

 <Button Name="btnMoreContent" Grid.Column="0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Viewbox MaxWidth="100" StretchDirection="Both">
                    <TextBlock Text="More Content" ></TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Button>
```

The font scales to fit the buttons. How can I grab the text size / scale value of the button with the smallest text at runtime and set them all to that size? 
I tried:

```
 double FontSize = btnContentButton.FontSize;
   if (FontSize < btnLongerContentButton.FontSize)
            {
                FontSize = btnLongerContentButton.FontSize;
            }

btnContentButton.FontSize = FontSize;
btnLongerContentButton.FontSize = FontSize;
```

But this doesn't work, because I never actually changed the font size - It sets them all to 12.

Comment: If you want to keep the font size, then why are you using Viewbox? There is only text in it.

Comment: It scales down the text to fit inside the textbox. Which works fine, but it looks a bit silly so I want them all to scale the same amount.

Comment: The shorter text doesn't scale at all because it doesn't need to, but I want it to scale the same amount as the boxes with the longer text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggested solutions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013854/how-do-i-keep-a-constant-fontsize-in-wpf-viewbox) and see if they can solve the problem.

However, you might want to try this one too: Handle Load event, find all `TextBlock`s with parent of type `ViewBox` (You might check other conditions or set proper names, to avoid further problems here), adjust their `Width`, properly, based on the `Width` of the one with the longest `Text`:

```
    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<TextBlock> tbs = new List<TextBlock>();
        TextBlock longestText = null;
        foreach (TextBlock t in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(this))
        {
            if (t.Parent is Viewbox)
            {
                tbs.Add(t);
                if (longestText == null)
                    longestText = t;
                else if (t.Text.Length > longestText.Text.Length)
                    longestText = t;
            }
        }
        double a = longestText.ActualWidth / longestText.ActualHeight;
        foreach (TextBlock tb in tbs)
        {
            if (tb == longestText)
                continue;
            tb.Width = a * tb.ActualHeight;
        }

    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`FindVisualChildren` method is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/978352/5615980).

Hope it helps.